# DataFrame to_json('gs://bucket/path') does not work

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-storage

I am being working on a GCP VM.
I'd like to use the command in python

```py
X.to_json("gs://bucket/path")
```

(which works on my local machine and on a colleague GCP VM)

However I have the following error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/path...`

I can read files from gs with the command pd.read_json("gs://...") but I cannot write. Moreover, the access scope of the VM is :

"Allow full access to all Cloud APIs"

Do you know what is the problem here?

## Edit :

I had to upgrade pandas version. The problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this as a community wiki. As you edited in your question, posting the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

It's possible that the newer version of pandas includes improvements or bug fixes related to GCS integration. So upgrading pandas version resolve these compatibility issues.

Refer this link on [Upgrade Pandas Version to Latest or Specific Version](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/upgrade-pandas-version-to-latest-or-specific-version/)